# What is the default configuration for the XFCE menu?

Tags: xfce, menu

I accidentally messed up my `xfce-applications.menu` file in `/etc/xdg/menus` ..... :(

Does anyone know what the default configuration is for this file?

Let's hope I learn my lesson of messing with the original file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the ppas for Xfce 4.10 and 4.12 on Xubuntu 12.04, but I think `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu` will be the same as in your version. I have pasted it at [Ubuntu paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5682499/), so you can retrieve it and reinstall it, logout and login again (but see my notes below).

The menu is in the package `libgarcon-common`:

```
libgarcon-common: /etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu
```

so this is useful to know, but a reinstall of the package won't replace the config file, and purging the package so it removes the config file would remove a lot of Xfce, so those really aren't options.

Another option would be to download the package from [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgarcon-common&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (or from the ppa if using one) for your particular Ubuntu version and extract the deb with your archive manager and manually copy `xfce-applications.menu` to `/etc/xdg/menus` with:

```
sudo cp ~/location/of/xfce-applications.menu /etc/xdg/menus
```

It is also best to edit the menus in `/home/$USER/.config/menus`, then you can use the menus in `/etc/xdg/menus` to replace them if you make any mistakes.